# Is it possible to generate Android Launcher Icons from CLI?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I want to create a Launcher Icon for an Android Application in Android Studio, I have to select the build variant, right-click onto `res`, select *New* > *Image Asset*, select the input file, configure everything*, click *Next*, select the correct `res` directory and click *Finish*.

That creates all the (currently) 23 files in the 6 `mipmap`y directories.

When I have many build variants and each and every one has to get its own launcher icon, that is a tedious process.

Is there any way to automate that?